# How to randomly send a request in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have a transaction in JMeter with 2 requests, one for accepting some data and one for rejecting it. I want JMeter to randomly send either the accept or the reject request for each iteration. How do I go about doing this? Is there an element in JMeter I can use or do I have to write a groovy script for it? If it's the latter then can someone help me with it cause I'm not very good with groovy.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is use [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) and use [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) as the "Switch Value"

[image]

This `${__Random(0,1,)}` expression will generate a random number between 0 and 1 inclusively each time it's being called therefore Switch Controller will invoke either first or second element randomly

[image]

More information: [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability)

Answer (score 0):

As you have 2 requests and you want to send one random request. One solution would be put the requests under random controller and you will hit a random request each time the controller is executed.
You can refer: [https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Controller[enter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Controller%5Benter) link description here][1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Controller)